# How to Set delay between different lines of code

Tags: c#

I'm working with Autodesk AutoCad API C# . I created 2 Line .how can I set delay between creating Line1 and Line 4. I want to have delay between creating these for lines in program.

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{ 
public class Class1
    {
        [CommandMethod("DrawLine1")]
        public static void CreateLine()
        {

            Document Mydoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database db = Mydoc.Database;
            Editor edit = Mydoc.Editor;


            using (Transaction Trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {

                BlockTable block;
                block = Trans.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;

                BlockTableRecord btr;
                btr = Trans.GetObject(block[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

                //Line1
                Point3d p1 = new Point3d(0, 0, 0);
                Point3d p2 = new Point3d(1000, 0, 0);
                Line line_1 = new Line(p1, p2);
                line_1.ColorIndex = 2;
                line_1.SetDatabaseDefaults();
                btr.AppendEntity(line_1);
                Trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(line_1, true);

                //Line2
                Point3d p3 = new Point3d(1200, 0, 0);
                Point3d p4 = new Point3d(2000, 0, 0);
                Line line_2 = new Line(p3, p4);
                line_2.ColorIndex = 2;
                line_2.SetDatabaseDefaults();
                btr.AppendEntity(line_2);
                Trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(line_2, true);

               

                Trans.Commit();


            }
        }

        }
```

http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-41a5.htm,topicNumber=d0e13987

Comment: Task.Delay(1000); ?

Comment: @Hazrelle no, it'd only create a task without waiting for it.

`Task.Delay(1000).Wait()` would do (or `await` in async method), but in sync method `Thread.Sleep` is more obvious choice

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Normally "stick a delay in" is covering up some other problem elsewhere that cannot cope with code running at full speed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.Sleep(1000);` to suspend the current thread for the specified amount of time. The 1000 is in milliseconds.

As @karolgro mentionned (see his example) in your case you should split the lines creation into separate transactions and set the delay between them, beacuse the actual save in database is done after the `trans.Commit()`.

Comment: I think in the transaction scope it may not solve the problem. You should probably close the transaction and create another after delay

Comment: You have a point there. It should be split into separate transactions between the Thread.Sleep delay as the actual save in database is done after the trans.Commit()

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce simply the delay in C#, by adding `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))`.

However, that probably won't be helpful, as I think all changes are sent in `Trans.Commit();` command. So if you want to add a line, wait and then add another line, you probably need sth like this:

```cs
/// this is only pseudocode
using (Transaction Trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    //Add a line
    Trans.Commit();
}

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

using (Transaction Trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    //Add another line
    Trans.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of doing this.

1. Using `System.Threading.Tasks` (recommended)

```cs
int t = 1000; // milliseconds - 1 second in this example

Task sleepTask = Task.Delay(t);

// then either do (which I don't recommend)
sleepTask.Wait();

// or better in an async method
await sleepTask;
```

2. Using `System.Threading`

```cs
int t = 1000; // same as above

Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

I'd recommend you to use `System.Threading.Tasks` as Tasks allow you to run code asynchronously, therefore not blocking any other threads like the GUI.

Comment: i wrote like this but it calculate all delay and put them in starting of program it doesn't set delays between lines.

Comment: @CaiusJard what do you mean?

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry I confused `Thread` and `Task`. It's fixed now, I changed `Task.Sleep` to `Task.Delay`.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `Task.Delay(t)` doesn't wait - it just returns a task. You need to call it with `await Task.Delay(t)` in async method (or `Task.Delay(t).Wait()` in other places, but I'd rather use `Thread` then)

Comment: @karolgro you are correct, I updated the code. I wrote this answer back when I didn't fully understand the concept of Tasks.